# Is there inverse overlap (&&) to array in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two arrays in postgresql and I would like to discover if they DO NOT overlap.

I've tried to use NOT with the operator, no success.

```
array[1,2,3] NOT && array[4,5]
```

Any ideia would be appreciate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just another try and I got this working

```
SELECT NOT(ARRAY[1,2,3] && ARRAY[4,5])
```